# Robohelp 8 Changing CHM Title Doesn't Work?

Tags: robohelp

I'm generating a Windows .chm file using Robohelp 8.  The title bar of the generated .chm file is incorrect and needs to be changed.  I've set the project title using File->Project settings, and regenerated the .chm file, but its title bar still has the old text.  Is there some other setting I need to make or file I need to rename or delete to get this to work?  I'd really like to have the help file reflect the current product name, rather than the old brand...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind; found it under Project Setup->Windows->HtmlHelp.